# Java Sound .WAV format

Tags: java, audio, wav, clip

I know this question has been asked a few times now about sound, and believe me, I have looked through to try and work out my own answer. I had the sound in Java working before on a different project without any difficulties using this:

```
public void playWelcome (){

  try{

    InputStream inputStream = 

    getClass().getResourceAsStream("Start.wav");

    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);

    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);

  }catch(IOException ioException){

    ioException.printStackTrace();

    System.out.println("Unable to Find WAV/Start FIle");
  }   
}
```

Obviously, this is not working before as explained so I have tried to use:

```
public void uploadDownload() {

  try {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 

    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new

    File("/DaWord/src/resources/upload.wav").getAbsoluteFile());

    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

    clip.open(audioInputStream); 

    clip.start();

  } catch(Exception ex) {

    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");

    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

NOTE: I have tried the file without the slashes too. e.g. 'my file.wav'
Can someone help me out a bit here?

UPDATE:

So I have managed to get it going.. sort of:

File soundFile = new File("/Users/myname/DaWord/src/testing.wav");

```
      AudioInputStream audioIn =
```

AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

```
     // Get a sound clip resource.
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

     // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
     clip.open(audioIn);

     clip.start();
```

But does anyone know how to do this by not providing the absolute path?? I have tried to use the .absoulutePath(); on the end of File such as : File

file = new File ("sound.wav").absouloutePath();

Comment: Have you tried using only : File AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new

File("/DaWord/src/resources/upload.wav"))?

Comment: hey just tried this , its a no go keep getting a null pointer exception in the output.. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html) this are the ways to allocate a AudioInputStream piped from a file or URL,:

```
// from a wave File
File soundFile = new File("eatfood.wav");
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
// from a URL
URL url = new URL("http://www.zzz.com/eatfood.wav");
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
// can read from a disk file and also a file contained inside a JAR (used for distribution)
// recommended
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("eatfood.wav");
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

Comment: Use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)` if you don't want files to be resolved relative to the class, resources resolved by `getClass().getResource()` will (if without a leading slash) be resolved relative to the specified class.

Comment: I just tried the from wav as well as the Url method... still not working for some odd  reason I keep getting a null pointer exception.. I have went over all the obvious such as the import for File IO as well as making sure the actual File is in the class/ resource and playing it to make sure theres nothing weird going on and its fine, odd

Answer (score 0):

This worked for the time being... with full path

File soundFile = new File("/Users/mrBerns/NetBeansProjects/DaWord/src/ching.wav");

```
      AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);              
     // Get a sound clip resource.
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();
```